# operator '&&'cannot be applied to 'int', 'int'

Tags: java, if-statement, operators

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode = 1 && resultCode = RESULT_OK && data!=null){
        imagePath = data.getData();
        getImageinImageView();
    }
}`
```

I don't understand why it gives me this error.

I'm trying to make a profile picture changer and when the picture is selected, it shows the new profile picture.

Comment: Use `==` instead of `=` inside the `if` comparisons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is a good example why it is "dangerous" to do equality comparisons:

`requestCode = 1 && resultCode = RESULT_OK && data!=null`

This could be split up in

- `requestCode = 1`
- and
- `resultCode = RESULT_OK`
- and
- `data != null`

Of the three comparisons probably only the last gets evaluated as you intended.
The first two are actually *assignements* that assign a value on the right side of the `=` to the variable on the left side. But even an assignement is evaluated to something and that something is the value that's assigned to the left side, so `requestCode = 1` not only assigns the `int` value `1` to `requestCode` but also evaluates to `1` in total.

Then the `int` results of the comparisons are combined via the `&&` operator, but that does only work on `boolean` values, and that is where the error comes from.

You probably wanted to write `requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null`.

(N.B.: in C it's even worse, because there you *can* combine ints with the && operator, and the whole statement would not be thrown back by the compiler. There you should always write the constant first, like `1 == requestCode` because even if you forget on of the `=`, the compiler cannot assign a value to the constant on the left side, while the comparison doesn't care about the order of the operands.)

Answer (score 1):

You wrote `requestCode = 1`   in if statement. You should write it `requestCode == 1`. Also you should write `resultCode == RESULT_OK`.

`=` and `==` are different.

Comment: Hi Ahmet, can you please also include some kind of explanation why this is so?

Comment: Hi buddy. `=`  is an assignment operator. it is used to assign the values to variables. 

`==` is an operator checks whether the two given operands are equal or not.  This returns true/false values. So this is used in if statements.